# Videojs-swf - rtmp connect without publishing stream or disconnect

Tags: actionscript-3, video.js, rtmp

How can I set waiting when the stream is not published.
When unpublish (NetStream.Play.UnpublishNotify) set to waiting, and on publish (NetStream.Play.PublishNotify) continue play

Comment: What have you tried? Show the function code that handles NetStream events so that it's faster & easier to help you fix problems...

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Video-JS so I don't know what their code setup is doing.

Normally (without Video-JS) it's done something like this.

```
yourNS.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, streamEventsHandler);

private function streamEventsHandler(evt:NetStatusEvent):void
{
    //trace(evt.info.code); //if you need to check event status as text
    if (evt.info.code == "NetStream.Play.UnpublishNotify") { yourNS.pause(); }
    if (evt.info.code == "NetStream.Play.PublishNotify") { yourNS.resume(); }
}
```

So now in the Video-JS code, find the part that handles NetStream events, and edit the function to `pause();` or `resume();`.

If unsure of the real NetStream name (I just called it `yourNS` for example) you can try :

Instead of : `yourNS.pause();` try as `evt.target.pause();` or `evt.target.pause();`

(PS: I use **evt** because of **the name in function parameter** is `(evt:NetStatusEvent):void`... Check your own Video-JS function)